# Anchor point inside a fixed scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a div(#results) that comes up when somebody inputs words into a text box that brings up results. This is a fixed div that is scrollable with pagination at the bottom of the scroll, when someone clicks say page 2(.gotoPage) ajax loads the second page of results in the fixed div but stays at the bottom of the scrollable div. Im using the code below but all this does is scroll the site content behind the fixed div up. Not to the top of the results where I placed an #search-top. Any suggestions how i can just make the results div scroll up instead of the site?

```
$( ".gotoPage" ).click(function() {
    var container = document.getElementById('results'); 
    var scrollTo = document.getElementById('search-top');
    container.scrollTop = scrollTo.offsetTop;
});
```

Comment: pleas provide jsfiddle for that

Comment: at least provide your html and css

Comment: It's complicated, i'm using something called algolia, its not just a simple popup after you search.

Basically just want to know if you can put an anchor point inside a scrollable div

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
container.scrollTop(scrollTo.offsetTop);
```